# Is default move semantic the same thing as copying?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

Is default move constructor/assingment operator making a copy?
Can I safely use moved object?
Example code:

```cpp
class Foo
{
private:
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    Foo(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
    Foo(Foo&&) = default;
    Foo& operator=(Foo&&) = default;
    void doSomethingWithMembers() {/* code */};
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo1 = Foo(5, 1);
    Foo foo2 = std::move(foo1); // Example operation 
    foo2 = std::move(foo1);     // Example operation
    foo1.doSomethingWithMembers(); // is it safe?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a move when you really want a copy? That is at least confusing, if not dangerous

Comment: It may work here and now, but don't count on it. Someone might change `Foo` later and it will stop working. Additionally, this is certainly not going to work as a general rule. The only thing you should count on from a moved-from instance is that it is destructible and assignable, unless otherwise guaranteed by the class' documentation.

Comment: In your case move and copy are effectively the same, but you should not rely on this behavior since this is not true in the general case.

Comment: This particular class reaps no benefit by moving, since it has no managed objects.

Comment: There is no advantage to moving a type that has only `int` members. So don't give it move semantics. Just provide a copy constructor and copy assignment operator.

Comment: In the `main` routine, after a move the object moved from is in a valid but unspecified state (suitable to be assigned to, or to be destructed).  Given this is your own code, you have knowledge of it's state, but in general once an object is moved from it can be considered to have one foot in the grave and another on a banana peel.  (The C++ standard has some objects with additional guarantees, such as `std::unique_ptr` that has been moved from can be checked for null.)

Comment: @Eljay "valid but unspecified" is the default for things in `std`. "valid and specified" and "invalid" are other possibilities for user-defined types (although the latter is problematic)

Answer (score 3):

In the example you posted, yes: the move constructor will perform the same operations as the copy constructor.

However, if the class contains (directly or indirectly) any user-defined types with move constructors, or if it inherits (directly or indirectly) from some other class with a move constructor, the two may differ in behavior.